# Sum of series = S

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $S=\frac35+\frac{10}{5^2}+\frac{21}{5^3}+\frac{36}{5^4}+\frac{55}{5^5}+\cdots$

In this we have to find value of S

Intianlly I thought it is geometric series .

After that I try to makes terms which can cancel other terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{S}{5} = \frac{3}{5^2}+\frac{10}{5^3}+\frac{21}{5^4}+\frac{36}{5^5}+\frac{55}{5^6}+\cdots$$
Hence
$$S_1 = \frac{4S}{5} = S - \frac{S}{5} = \frac{3}{5}+\frac{7}{5^2}+\frac{11}{5^3}+\frac{15}{5^4}+\frac{19}{5^6}+\cdots$$
$$\frac{1}{5}S_1 = \frac{3}{5^2}+\frac{7}{5^3}+\frac{11}{5^4}+\frac{15}{5^5}+\frac{19}{5^7}+\cdots$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{5}S_1 &= \frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5^2} + \frac{4}{5^3} + \cdots \\
&=\frac{3}{5} +\frac{4}{5^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{5}}\\
&= \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{5} = \frac{4}{5}
\end{align*}
Hence $S_1 = 1$ and $S = \frac{5}{4}$

Answer (score 4):

These seem to be alternate triangular numbers: is this the case?
If so the series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n(2n+1)}{5^n}.$$
This is $f(1/5)$ where
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(2n+1)x^n.$$
If you can sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n$
then you can sum this.

Comment: How to solve second term (sum)

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$. Then $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Differentiating, we get $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$. To get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n$, compute $x\frac{d}{dx}(xf'(x))$